# wordpress custom admin pages

Tags: wordpress, cms

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли в wordpress (4.6) как то переделать админку отдельные страници, например чтобы юзер видел только свои посты. Плагины и скрипты в functions не совсем подходят, потому как хочу "изолировать" автора от остальных пользователей чтобы он также не видел буквально ничего от других пользователей а на странице комментарии счетчики неправильно работают и при добавлении поста отображаются категории других пользователей. хочу обойтись без леса функций как то по елегантней.
Если просуммировать вопрос таков - как подменить частично админку костомными тимплейтами, спасибо за идеи.

Comment: создавайте свои роли пользователей, назначайте им нужные вам права. В вордпресс для этого отличные возможности

Comment: @alenkins ну так пользователю автор виден весь список статей, и счетчики вверху  учитывают "всех" авторов статьи, сдесь как бы задача чтобы автор кроме своих данных, настроек - больше ничего не видел. Спасибо за комментарий, если есть еще идеи буду благодарен.